# log4j not splitting log files after 1MB

Tags: logging, log4j

I have following `log4j` config file

```
log = /home/dummydata/my-logs
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FILE
# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/mylogs.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Its working fine, but it is not splitting log file after 1MB. All logs are being appended in same file `mylogs.log`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The names of appenders are [case-sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity). So you've actually configured two appenders, `FILE` and `file`.

In another way, the first element in the value for `log4j.rootLogger` is the default level (e.g. `INFO` or `DEBUG`) (required), and the next elements are the appender names (e.g. `FILE`, `CONSOLE`) (one is required).

Thus, the corrected file:

```
log = /home/dummydata/my-logs
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE
# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/mylogs.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1MB
# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

If you want to show how you log4j renaming files, appended to this file:

```
log4j.debug
```

Comment: with this config there are several problem: `1.` Its not splitting file after 1MB but after 10MB `2.` Its not recreating log file if i delete log file it doesn't create new log file